# Find $f$ such that $f(af(b))=bf(a)$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+, f(af(b))=bf(a)$$

$f(x)=x$ is a trivial solution, but I'm not sure if this is the only one.

I can see that $f(f(x))=x$ and therefore $f$ is bijective, but not anything else.

Comment: I believe $f(x)=\frac 1x$ may be another solution...

Comment: I see $f(f(x))=xf(1)$ so,  if $f(1)=0$ , it's not bijective

Comment: @lulu, the range is $\mathbb{R}^{+}.$

Comment: Ah, missed that.  But  still,  there's the $f(1)$

Comment: This seems like it's a duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2646128/1104384